# php and mysqli num_rows all the time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

my company has a big website, sells all kind of products.

So, for example, one product here has +1000 comments and has been sold more than +4000.

our sell table in mysql has more than 1.000.000 rows of sold products.

so we do:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, product_code, product_desc, price FROM sell where id='$id'");
```

after that a num_rows to get all this product.

same to get this product comments, product likes, marks...

ours website is slow.

my question is, all that num_rows may be cause this problem? should us instead of doing num_rows all the time, just create a table that increase number in each sell, comment... and just get this value?

**in other words, is this num_rows a good practise or not in this case?**

Comment: try assoc. I think it's much better.

Comment: what you are thinking to put the count as a different field can be good if you are having loads of data in your table, but try putting it in products table, so that you can get the counts while you are fetching the product. so no need to fire another query...

Comment: @gabriela when you dont know wether the code will help you or not.. than at that time `trial and error` is the best practice...

Answer (score 0):

That might not be the `NUM_ROWS` that causing the slowness, that probably the query itself.
Here are the possible improvements:

> 1. Indexes. Do your tables have indexes? I would suggest to create an index by ID column.
> 2. Statistics. Do you have your tables analyzed?
> 3. Review the database structure. You might not need the product description in the SELL table. Product ID may be enough. If you drop unnecessary columns from the table, it will be lighter and better performing.

UPD: You can rewrite your query like this to have the value in the results:

```
SELECT id, product_code, product_desc, price, count(*) as cnt
  FROM sell where id='$id'
 GROUP BY id, product_code, product_desc, price
```

And you'll have `cnt` value which is the amount of rows returned.

Comment: @GabrielaDias, Nope, you need the GROUP BY clause and need to name the specific columns (the * will lead to an error).

Answer (score 0):

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) as num FROM sell where id='$id'");

Comment: SELECT * , count( * ) as num
FROM `sell`
WHERE `id` = '$id'
GROUP BY `product_code`

Answer (score 0):

After reading to your question, i think you are dealing with huge database and here.
I prefer you to go with datatable, where you have an option called Serveside: true
Using datatables you will be able to handle huge amount of data at very ease (this is for your future purpose also for your company website) I personally implemented this to one of our client website and the result is just awsome and you can bring the count and listing of data by using limits which will not put much load on your DATABASE
Try out with example here in the link [Data tables](https://www.datatables.net/)